# Comparison of two separate Data Access Layers (DALs) of a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, profiling, profiler

I have two separate DALs of a project and I want to compare them to see which one is the better DAL with regards to performance. The performance metrics that I have in mind are memory, execution time of queries etc.
The problems that I have faced are:

1) I have used visual studio profiler and generated two reports but in some cases the values that are common to both projects don't match up.(I have read that for this instrumentation is to blame)

2) Also I have an insert method in both DAL's whose performance I want to compare so when I use the compare reports option it does not show a value since the comparison is of methods in different projects.

[image: Value missing]

Any suggestions to the approach I can use will be helpful.

Also , is profiling the only method to judge application performance,for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiling tools usually heavily distort the measurements, it's not surprising that the results you get are inconsistent.

I would suggest just using Stopwatch to measure a loop of let's say 100000 DB access operations through each of the DAL's. You can measure average time per one operation, and the test duration in total.

While the loop is running, have Perfmon display counters of CPU, `.NET CLR Memory\# Bytes in all heaps`, `.NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC`. It would be also useful to measure transaction throughput from the database, like `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\Transactions/sec` and `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS:SQL Statistics\Batch Requests/sec` (assuming you use SQL Express; other DBMS usually supply similar counters as well).

I think this should give you quite enough information to decide.

Comment: the stopwatch has really helped. can you also suggest a similar solution if I want to see the time taken to execute the queries??